# Why is First Responder `nil` after startup?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, first-responder

Here is a minimal working example illustrating the issue: https://bitbucket.org/7331/firstrespondertest/.

---

What object is set as the First Responder of the `keyWindow` after the Single View Application starts up (suppose that I haven't interacted with the application yet and my code doesn't explicitly call `becomeFirstResponder()`)?

In other words – what object sets the First Responder to the initial value? (Or what is the First Responder of a newly created `UIWindow`?)

As I was debugging the Single View Application, I inspected* the First Responder of the `keyWindow` and found out that it was `nil` – which seems odd given that the `ViewController`'s `motionBegan()` gets called when the device is shaken (despite the fact that `canBecomeFirstResponder()` returns `false`).

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func canBecomeFirstResponder() -> Bool {
        return false
    }

    override func motionBegan(motion: UIEventSubtype, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        print("motionBegan")
    }
}
```

Moreover: when I load a `nib` file via `UINib`, do the `nib`'s subviews get called `becomeFirstResponder()` by `UINib`'s initializer internally?

---

*I used the `UIWindow`'s private API to inspect the First Responder.
In LLDB:
`po UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow!._firstResponder()`.